# Protocol declaration with delegate & Datasource for UIPageController with ScrollView having several views in same page

Tags: memory-management, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am following these codes from

1) http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/09/26/uipagecontrol-uiscrollview/#comment-955

2) https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

Now the thing I am looking to implement in my application following these example in custom way: (CustomController of MyOwn)

```
- (void)setupPage; of Jones link
```

I want to have several small views just like cubes/ Sudoko ... in each View of Scrollview rather than ImageView & giving event to each small view. I view will have around 20views in each Page of ScrollView. How can I implement this things by creating my own Protocols, defining datasource & delegate methods.

**Structure would be like this:**

```
-->UIScrollView
    -->View1
        -->around 20 smallViews with each having events so that user can move to next view to show detail explanation.
    -->View1
        -->around 20 smallViews with each having events so that user can move to next view to show detail explanation.

    -->View1
        -->around 20 smallViews with each having events so that user can move to next view to show detail explanation.

    …n number of Views.
```

[image]

There will be such screens like this in each Page of Scrollview.How to handle this with making new class called Tile which itself is a view.

Although I am sure to do this thing in my own way, but that is like scratch method, & called very poor programming. But I want to do this in smarter way, so that I can use the same thing in other classes to, that would reduce my coding & making good impression to my Client ;)

Additionally, I know there I would have to take care of memory management!

Answer (score 0):

Give each smaller view an identifier (for example, use the `UIView` proper `tag`) then, in your delegate/data-source/etc., just do the thing appropriate to whichever view you want.  Example:

```
// In view setup:
// ... (your other setup)
someSmallView.tag = ++nextIndex;

// ...

// In delegate code:
switch (scrollView.tag)
{
    case 1:
        // ... blah blah
        break;
    case 2:
        // ... etc
}
```

NOTE: if you're using interface builder to create your view, you can set the tag there.